# What is the most minimal bootable kernel example?

Tags: kernel, bios, uefi

["Hello World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) programs can be seen as the most minimal userspace program example for a given language, i.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   printf("Hello, World!");
   return 0;
}
```

for C. It serves the purpose of showing how to write the most minimal interface required for a callable program (a `main()` function) and some text printing using `printf()`.

Is it possible to create such a minimal "Hello World" example for a BIOS/EFI-bootable kernel? What would such a bootable interface and possibly a print operation look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a EDK2-based `HelloWorld` which can be run from an EFI shell prompt.

```
#include <Uefi.h>
#include <Library/UefiLib.h>
#include <Library/ShellCEntryLib.h>

INTN
EFIAPI
ShellAppMain( UINTN Argc, CHAR16 **Argv)
{
    Print(L"Hello World!\n");

    return(0);
}
```